# replace first 2 character of a string using xsl

Tags: xml, string, xslt, replace, character

I have an issue. I need to modify the fist 2 values of an xml element using xsl command.

something like this:

```
<hello>00100</hello>    -->>  <hello>99100</hello>
```

I red that there is a function called replace that could do the thing, but I have no idea how to use it.

do you know if it's possible to perform this operation with xsl?
in case do you have a link to some readings about it, or even better a sample?
thanks in advance.

Comment: _"but I have no idea how to use it"_ -- read the documentation, then experiment.  THEN if you still can't get it to work update your post showing what you tried and what is actually happening.

Comment: I am using XSLT 1,0

Comment: Can you also expand on the logic required. Do you want to replace the first two characters with "99" regardless of what the first two characters are? Or only if the first two characters are "00"? What if the first two characters are "01", for example, should that stay as "01" or become "91"?

Comment: yes, I don't need to know the content of the two characters. I can replace it directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to react to the first two characters you can use the `substring()` function like this

```
substring(text(),3)
```

which selects all characters after the second (XSLT starts counting at one). So your XSLT-1.0 code could be:

```
<xsl:template match="hello" >
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('99',substring(text(),3))" />
</xsl:template>
```

This replaces the first two characters of the text() content of `<hello>` elements with `99`.